# it keeps given the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' python boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

i have a basic python boto3 query where it gives error while running. I have a list of IntanceIds in which one of them is decommissioned and has no data but other two has still running and has data in it.

I want to make sure that when i iterate those instances to find their tags, it wont give me the error below. Instead, it will ignore the decommission instance and give me the result of tags of another 2 instances:

Here's my code:

```
import boto3
InstanceIds = ['I-1234', 'I-2345', 'I-6789']
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
for inst in InstanceIds:
    instance_response = ec2.Instance(inst)
    if instance_response is None:
        print(instance_response, " has a value of None")
    else:
        instance_tags = instance_response.tags
        for item in instance_tags:
            if item['Key'] == 'Environment':
                val = item['Value']
        pattern = re.compile(r'\bpr\w*', re.IGNORECASE)
        matches = pattern.findall(val)
        if matches:
            print("Prod Tag exists in ", inst, val)
        else:
            nonPRD_tags_exists_instances.append(inst)
            print("Prod Tag doesn't exists in ", inst, val) 
print(nonPRD_tags_exists_instances)
```

It still gives me an error:

```
    instance_tags = instance_response.tags
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 386, in property_loader
    return self.meta.data.get(name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: And fix the indentation of your code. the `if` statement must be at the same indentation as `instance_response =`

Comment: fixed the indentation code

Comment: I would guess that the response isnt a None value for the instance that doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you `print(instance_response.__dict__)`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have got this response: ```{'meta': ResourceMeta('ec2', identifiers=['id']), '_id': 'i-1234'}
{'meta': ResourceMeta('ec2', identifiers=['id']), '_id': 'i-2345'}
{'meta': ResourceMeta('ec2', identifiers=['id']), '_id': 'i-6789'}```

Comment: Does that instance have tags? If not, you might need to wrap the failing line of code in a `try` statement to handle situation where there are no tags.